# Upgrading Windows 7 to Windows 8 when dual booting with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot

I am dual booting between Windows 8 Enterprise (90 day evaluation copy) and Windows 7 Home Edition.

If I upgrade Windows 7 Home Edition to Windows 8, will there be any issues with having both versions installed?

Answer (score 3):

No.
Upgrading one OS will not affect other OSs on the same computer.

---

In general, the only risk you would face in such a scenario is that the upgrade might replace the boot loader, leaving you unable to boot to the other OS until you re-install or reconfigure the boot loader.

This is only an issue if the secondary OS is not Windows, or is a newer version of Windows.